# Can I replace context with hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Is there a way with new react hooks API to replace a context data fetch?

If you need to load user profile and use it almost everywhere, first you create context and export it:

```
export const ProfileContext = React.createContext()
```

Then you import in top component, load data and use provider, like this:

```
import { ProfileContext } from 'src/shared/ProfileContext'

<ProfileContext.Provider
      value={{ profile: profile, reloadProfile: reloadProfile }}
    >
        <Site />
    </ProfileContext.Provider>
```

Then in some other components you import profile data like this:

```
import { ProfileContext } from 'src/shared/ProfileContext'
const context = useContext(profile);
```

But there is a way to export some function with hooks that will have state and share profile with any component that want to get data?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

React provides a useContext hook to make use of Context, which has a signature like

```
const context = useContext(Context);
```

> `useContext` accepts a context object (the value returned from
>   React.createContext) and returns the current context value, as given
>   by the nearest context provider for the given context.
>
> When the provider updates, this Hook will trigger a rerender with the
>   latest context value.

You can make use of it in your component like

```
import { ProfileContext } from 'src/shared/ProfileContext'

const Site = () => {
   const context = useContext(ProfileContext);
   // make use of context values here
}
```

However if you want to make use of the same context in every component and don't want to import the `ProfileContext` everywhere you could simply write a custom hook like

```
import { ProfileContext } from 'src/shared/ProfileContext'
const useProfileContext = () => {
   const context = useContext(ProfileContext);
   return context;
}
```

and use it in the components like

```
const Site = () => {
   const context = useProfileContext();
}
```

However as far a creating a hook which shares data among different component is concerned, Hooks have an instance of the data for them self and don'tshare it unless you make use of Context;

Comment: so i still need to wrap top level component in provider to get all components updated on data change?

Comment: @RTWTMI, yes you would still need a Provider at top level, useContext is a replacement for `MyComponent.contextTypes = ProfileContext`

Answer (score 3):

**updated:**

My previous answer was - You can use custom-hooks with useState for that purpose, but it was wrong because of this fact:

> **Do two components using the same Hook share state?** No. Custom Hooks are a mechanism to reuse stateful logic (such as setting up a subscription and remembering the current value), but every time you use a custom Hook, all state and effects inside of it are fully isolated.

The right answer how to do it with useContext() provided @ShubhamKhatri

Comment: But this will not change my todo data in another component, if i change it somewhere :(

Comment: No, it will... you put useTodoState() to it's own file and import it in whatever file you want and it will be working with one state (that's why i named the component "OneOfTodoViewers")

Comment: hm, i will test it again then :/

Comment: Sorry, my fault and you are right. Custom hooks don't share their state, but only logic. So @ShubhamKhatri answered correctly

Answer (score 0):

Now i use it like this.

Contexts.js - all context export from one place

```
export { ClickEventContextProvider,ClickEventContext} from '../contexts/ClickEventContext'
export { PopupContextProvider, PopupContext } from '../contexts/PopupContext'
export { ThemeContextProvider, ThemeContext } from '../contexts/ThemeContext'
export { ProfileContextProvider, ProfileContext } from '../contexts/ProfileContext'
export { WindowSizeContextProvider, WindowSizeContext } from '../contexts/WindowSizeContext'
```

ClickEventContext.js - one of context examples:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

export const ClickEventContext = React.createContext(null)
export const ClickEventContextProvider = props => {
  const [clickEvent, clickEventSet] = useState(false)
  const handleClick = e => clickEventSet(e)

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('click', handleClick)
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('click', handleClick)
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <ClickEventContext.Provider value={{ clickEvent }}>
      {props.children}
    </ClickEventContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

import and use:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from 'react'
import { ClickEventContext } from 'shared/Contexts'

export function Modal({ show, children }) {
  const { clickEvent } = useContext(ClickEventContext)

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(clickEvent.target)
  }, [clickEvent])

  return <DivModal show={show}>{children}</DivModal>
}
```